# Using the VLC backend with phonon in Qt (Windows)

Tags: qt, phonon

I'm trying to make an media player application with Qt and the phonon library.
Everything goes well when I'm playing a SD DivX, but when I'm trying to play a 12 GB HD MKV it's freezing (with a I7, 8GB RAM, NV GTX260).

Currently I'm using the default backend (phonon_ds94.dll). I would like to use the phonon_vlc.dll one but I don't know how to make the switch. Any one have an idea ?

Thank you,
Sébastien

Comment: How about the solution for this?